# how to move all 4 corner individually

Tags: modeling

I have a empty and with array modifier. Im moving. how to move all 4 corner individually .
And i have 4 corner only 3 are moving. Any suggestion how to move all 4 corner same position.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's hard to understand, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots file attached

Comment: doesn't seem easy, are you sure you want to do that with the Array modifier?

Comment: @moonboots is there any other option

Comment: Is it for an animation?

Comment: Have tried moving the object instead of the empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying seems hard to do with the *Arra*y modifier, you could try with the *Mirror* modifier, and use an empty as *Object*:

[image]